# Issue reinstalling package Phyloseq after updating R to v4.3.0: "fatal error: zstd.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: r, phyloseq, zstd

I just installed new Ubuntu updates, and apparently it contained a new version of R (4.3.0), which I didn't realize. I ended up having to reinstall some packages, but there is one that I am having issues, which is 'Phyloseq'. This is the error message I get:

```
blosc.c:37:12: fatal error: zstd.h: No such file or directory
   37 |   #include "zstd.h"
      |            ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I tried installing Phyloseq from the terminal as root, but it didn't work either. Also, I checked whether *zstd* is installed, and it's there (v1.4.4). Any ideas how to solve it? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Many thanks in advance!

---

This is the full output of the installation command
`BiocManager::install("phyloseq")`

```
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see 'help("repositories", package = "BiocManager")' for details.
Replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cloud.r-project.org
Bioconductor version 3.17 (BiocManager 1.30.20), R 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
Installing package(s) 'phyloseq'
also installing the dependencies ‘rhdf5filters’, ‘rhdf5’, ‘biomformat’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/bioc/src/contrib/rhdf5filters_1.12.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2959706 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/bioc/src/contrib/rhdf5_2.44.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1249545 bytes (1.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/bioc/src/contrib/biomformat_1.28.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 301144 bytes (294 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 294 KB

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.17/bioc/src/contrib/phyloseq_1.44.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5689663 bytes (5.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.4 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rhdf5filters’ ...
** using staged installation
configuring the BLOSC filter...
x86_CPU=true
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether C compiler accepts -msse2... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -mavx2... yes
checking for gcc __builtin_cpu_init function... (cached) true
checking for x86 sse2 instruction support... yes
checking for x86 avx2 instruction support... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/blosc/lib/blosc-1.20.1/Makefile
config.status: creating src/blosc/Makefile
configure:    BZIP2_LIB=bzip2/libH5Zbz2.so
configure:    BLOSC_LIB=blosc/libH5Zblosc.so
configure:    LZF_LIB=lzf/libH5Zlzf.so
configure:    VBZ_LIB=vbz/libH5Zvbz.so
configure:    ZSTD_LIB=zstd/libH5Zzstd.so
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/blosc/lib/blosc-1.20.1/Makefile
config.status: creating src/blosc/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
using C compiler: ‘gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0’
make -C zstd
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/zstd'
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c common/debug.c -o common/debug.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c common/entropy_common.c -o common/entropy_common.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c common/error_private.c -o common/error_private.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c common/fse_decompress.c -o common/fse_decompress.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c common/pool.c -o common/pool.o -o common/pool.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c common/threading.c -o common/threading.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c common/xxhash.c -o common/xxhash.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c common/zstd_common.c -o common/zstd_common.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/fse_compress.c -o compress/fse_compress.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/hist.c -o compress/hist.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/huf_compress.c -o compress/huf_compress.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_compress.c -o compress/zstd_compress.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_compress_literals.c -o compress/zstd_compress_literals.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_compress_sequences.c -o compress/zstd_compress_sequences.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_compress_superblock.c -o compress/zstd_compress_superblock.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_double_fast.c -o compress/zstd_double_fast.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_fast.c -o compress/zstd_fast.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_lazy.c -o compress/zstd_lazy.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_ldm.c -o compress/zstd_ldm.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstd_opt.c -o compress/zstd_opt.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c compress/zstdmt_compress.c -o compress/zstdmt_compress.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c decompress/huf_decompress.c -o decompress/huf_decompress.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c decompress/zstd_ddict.c -o decompress/zstd_ddict.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c decompress/zstd_decompress.c -o decompress/zstd_decompress.o
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I. -I./common -DXXH_NAMESPACE=ZSTD_ -DZSTD_DISABLE_ASM -c decompress/zstd_decompress_block.c -o decompress/zstd_decompress_block.o
rm -f libzstd.a
ar cq libzstd.a common/debug.o common/entropy_common.o common/error_private.o common/fse_decompress.o common/pool.o common/threading.o common/xxhash.o common/zstd_common.o compress/fse_compress.o compress/hist.o compress/huf_compress.o compress/zstd_compress.o compress/zstd_compress_literals.o compress/zstd_compress_sequences.o compress/zstd_compress_superblock.o compress/zstd_double_fast.o compress/zstd_fast.o compress/zstd_lazy.o compress/zstd_ldm.o compress/zstd_opt.o compress/zstdmt_compress.o decompress/huf_decompress.o decompress/zstd_ddict.o decompress/zstd_decompress.o decompress/zstd_decompress_block.o
ranlib libzstd.a
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -shared H5Zzstd.c -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" \
libzstd.a -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o libH5Zzstd.so
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/zstd'
make -C blosc
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/blosc'
make -C lib/snappy-1.1.1
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/blosc/lib/snappy-1.1.1'
g++ -std=gnu++17 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -c snappy.cc
g++ -std=gnu++17 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -c snappy-c.cc
g++ -std=gnu++17 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -c snappy-sinksource.cc
g++ -std=gnu++17 -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -c snappy-stubs-internal.cc
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/blosc/lib/snappy-1.1.1'
make -C lib/lz4-1.9.4
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/blosc/lib/lz4-1.9.4'
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -c lz4.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -c lz4hc.c
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/blosc/lib/lz4-1.9.4'
make -C lib/blosc-1.20.1 all
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/blosc/lib/blosc-1.20.1'
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -c bitshuffle-avx2.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -c shuffle-avx2.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -c bitshuffle-sse2.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -c shuffle-sse2.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -c bitshuffle-generic.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -c shuffle-generic.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -DSHUFFLE_SSE2_ENABLED -DSHUFFLE_AVX2_ENABLED -c shuffle.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -c blosclz.c
gcc -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fpic -I"/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/Rhdf5lib/include" -I../lz4-1.9.4 -I../snappy-1.1.1 -I../zstd-1.4.5 -msse2 -mavx2 -c blosc.c
blosc.c:37:12: fatal error: zstd.h: No such file or directory
   37 |   #include "zstd.h"
      |            ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/blosc/lib/blosc-1.20.1'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:28: blosc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:39: blosc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/Rtmpc8Fxc6/R.INSTALL2b49235ec4b9/rhdf5filters/src/blosc'
make: *** [Makevars:37: libH5Zblosc.so] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rhdf5filters’
* removing ‘/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/rhdf5filters’
ERROR: dependency ‘rhdf5filters’ is not available for package ‘rhdf5’
* removing ‘/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/rhdf5’
ERROR: dependency ‘rhdf5’ is not available for package ‘biomformat’
* removing ‘/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/biomformat’
ERROR: dependency ‘biomformat’ is not available for package ‘phyloseq’
* removing ‘/home/meb/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/phyloseq’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmptEU44k/downloaded_packages’
Installation paths not writeable, unable to update packages
  path: /usr/lib/R/library
  packages:
    boot, foreign, lattice, MASS, Matrix, spatial
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘rhdf5filters’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘rhdf5’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘biomformat’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘phyloseq’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Just fixed it. Looks like there was an issue with the package **libzstd-dev**. I installed it via terminal with `sudo apt-get install -y libzstd-dev` and now I managed to reinstall Phyloseq.